# Adding Mcrypt to the heroku buildpack for ruby

Tags: ruby, heroku, mcrypt, buildpack

I need to use mcrypt on my server for connection with a third party api, however, our servers are located on heroku and the buildpack doesn't include mcrypt. Does anyone have an example of adding mcrypt to the heroku buildpack for ruby?

Thank you!

Comment: To answer my own issues, it's possible to just use the openssl library built in rails as long as you know that the encryption uses the correct padding. I made a gist of the encryption I needed.

https://gist.github.com/turlockmike/e441a32bf59f6e3c1544